# select query statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Hy all..I have an issue regarding a query.I have 3 tables and what I want to do is combine them to get to a good looking result.So I have the following 3 tables:

```
  personal
- cod_numeric_personal
- nume


  Raspunsuri
- raspuns
- cod_numeric_personal
- data_raspuns
- id_intrebare

  Intrebari
-intrebari
-id_intrebare
```

I did this query:

```
SELECT personal.nume, Raspunsuri.raspuns, Intrebari.intrebari
FROM personal
INNER JOIN Raspunsuri ON personal.cod_numeric_personal = Raspunsuri.cod_numeric_personal
INNER JOIN Intrebari ON Raspunsuri.id_intrebare = Intrebari.id_intrebare
```

This brings up the name of the user,the answer and the question for each answer.What I want is to bring up the name only once and the each question that is "intrebare" to be tha name of the column and for each column the answer.So like..Intrebare1...Answer1...but Intrebare1 being the name of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT personal.nume, Raspunsuri.raspuns, Intrebari.intrebari AS Answer
FROM personal
INNER JOIN Raspunsuri ON personal.cod_numeric_personal = Raspunsuri.cod_numeric_personal
INNER JOIN Intrebari ON Raspunsuri.id_intrebare = Intrebari.id_intrebare
Group By nume
```